# Replace Text with Images (Logos)

Tags: excel, vba, automation, powerpoint

I have a very standard ppt deck for my current consulting case that we reproduce four times a week in different varieties, and I am looking to build a macro to replace the names of companies with logos throughout the deck. I don't even need the logos to *replace* the text per se as much as I just need them to be placed where the company names are in the ppt.

Currently, we use a macro to populate most of the deck. However, how would one go about building a image-text replacement macro in ppt?

I've tried modifying the macro / automator we currently have, but while I'm able to replace text with text, I can't replace text with images.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace text by an image. Try this in Powerpoint: If you have a shape with text, you cannot assign an image to it.

So what you will have to do is to add a picture at the same place where the logo placeholder is. The following routine will look for a shape with a specific text. If found, it will place the logo picture at this position and hide the logo placeholder (if you prefer, you can delete it).

```
Sub AddLogo(slide As slide, logoText As String, LogoFilename As String)
    Const LogoShapeName = "LogoImage"
    Dim shape As shape, pic As shape
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pic = slide.Shapes(LogoShapeName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not pic Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' Logo already present
    
    For Each shape In slide.Shapes
        If shape.HasTextFrame Then
            If shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters = logoText Then
                Set pic = slide.Shapes.AddPicture(LogoFilename, msoFalse, msoCTrue, shape.Left, shape.Top)
                pic.Name = "LogoImage"
                shape.Visible = msoFalse    ' Hide Logo Placeholder
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Now all you have to do is to loop over all slides of a presentation and call this routine. Set the two constants to your needs.

```
Sub SetAllLogos()
    Const LogoPlaceholderText = "Logo"
    Const LogoFilename = "path\to\logo.jpg"

    Dim slide As slide
    For Each slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        AddLogo slide, LogoPlaceholderText, LogoFilename  
    Next
End Sub
```